# Нужна ли запятая перед «как»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

**Читателю невдомёк(?) как автор сумел так пёстро и внушительно обрисовать характер героя.**

Answer (score 3):

У нас СПП с двумя основами - *невдомёк* и *автор сумел обрисовать*.

Союз *как* открывает придаточное предложение - запятая нужна.

*Читателю невдомёк, как автор сумел так пёстро и внушительно обрисовать характер героя.*

Вызывает большие сомнения *пёстро и внушительно обрисованный характер*, но это уже не к пунктуации вопрос.